# Import from Team Foundation Server 2005 into 2008

Tags: tfs, import, tfs-2005

We have an existing TFS 2005 install and a newer 2008. The 2008 server already has some newer projects on it but I am looking to move the older projects from 2005 onto this newer server.

Does anyone know an easy way to do this and maintain the audit history rather than just break source control on the project and then add it to the 2008 server?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used the TFS to TFS migration tool to do this:

http://www.codeplex.com/tfstotfsmigration

You do need to have a copy of SQL local to the machine on which you run it which the tool uses as a copy area between the two.

Also, all the history will appear as if all changes happened on the same day due to how TFS stores the version history information.  Depending on your needs it may be easier to make the break and leave the 2005 database up until that history is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many new projects you've added, is it possible for you to restore the 2005 databases to the new server, upgrade them to 2008, and then migrate the newer projects into this newly updated database? That way, you'd maintain your entire TFS history, and you'd only have the "every change on a single day" problem for your small number of new projects.