# TFS: upgrade 2005 to 2008 and migrate to new hardware simultaneously

Tags: tfs, tfs-migration, tfs-2005

Our current environment has TFS on a single server installation:

- Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition SP2 (32-bit)
- TFS 2005
- SQL Server 2005 Standard Edition

Due to an ongoing drive towards virtualisation in our organisation, we are required to move TFS to new hardware.  As we have a licence for TFS 2008 we would like to end up with the following, again on a single server installation:

- Windows Server 2008 32-bit
- TFS 2008
- SQL Server 2008 Enterprise Edition (we need this licence level to be able to move machines around on the virtual envionrment)

Most importantly, we must retain our code check-in history.  Ideally, we would like to retain all our check-in dates and notes too.

I have found a couple of questions on SO that are similar:

[Attach and upgrade TFS 2005 databases to a TFS 2008 installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713872/attach-and-upgrade-tfs-2005-databases-to-a-tfs-2008-installation)

[Import from Team Foundation Server 2005 into 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442239/import-from-team-foundation-server-2005-into-2008)

However the first answer says to just read the manual, and having looked through it I can't find guidance on this specific scenario.  The second question is a slightly different scenario as we don't already have any projects on the new TFS environment - we haven't even built it yet!  We have the benefit of starting with a brand new TFS 2008 installation.

The question is then, what is the best way of doing this, if any?  We can set up the new environment and use the [TFS Integration Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f854dd59-8eeb-4673-8d9a-ae012989bfa2) but due to the limitations we will lose some information (e.g. check-in notes).

I'm thinking that there must surely be a way of upgrading the TFS 2005 databases to the 2008 version and attaching them to the new SQL Server?

If anyone can advise I'll be extremely grateful.

**Update**
Would it be possible to backup and then upgrade the *existing* TFS 2005 installation to 2008, and then perform a migration as per [these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)?

Comment: Why do you want to stay on TFS2008 and not move to TFS2010?

Comment: @Richard - Because we don't have the licence for it. I've only been in the organisation for a couple of months, but I believe we had MS Software Assurance for three years from the purchase of TFS 2005.  That covers 2008, but not 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Edward for his advice which made complete sense.  Unfortunately on looking into doing this, I discovered that TFS 2005 is not supported on Windows Server 2008 so I couldn't do it that way round.

I ended up doing what I initially suggested (in place upgrade and then migration).  I have listed the steps below in case anyone else ever wants to do this.  Please note that these steps are in no way exhaustive but they are the general process you need to follow with pointers to the correct documentation.

**New server:**

1. Set up Windows Server 2008
2. Install prerequisites (IIS, SQL
   2008) according to the [TFS 2008
   installation guide](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=15743)
3. Merge the TFS 2008 installation
   files with TFS 2008 SP1 in order to
   support SQL 2008 [(same installation guide)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=15743)
4. Install TFS 2008 SP1
   [(same installation guide)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=15743)
5. Upgrade SQL 2008 to SP2 to fix a bug
   which prevented maintenance plans
   from running without SSIS
6. Back up TFS and SharePoint databases
7. Back up the SSRS encryption key

**Old server:**

1. Take image of server for backup
2. Stop TFS/IIS services for robust
   database backup
3. Back up TFS and SharePoint databases
4. Back up the SSRS encryption key
5. Verify SQL 2005 SP1 is installed to
    support TFS 2008
6. Upgrade TFS 2005 > TFS 2008 as per
    [TFS 2008 installation guide](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=15743)
7. Install TFS 2008 SP1 to support SQL
    2008
8. Back up TFS and SharePoint
    databases
9. Back up the SSRS encryption key
10. Upgrade SQL 2005 > SQL 2008 as per
     [MSDN guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee175815%28v=vs.90%29.aspx#c304e51f-52a5-4f06-a34a-798c6f38a4aa)
11. Back up TFS and SharePoint
     databases
12. Back up the SSRS encryption key
13. Upgrade Windows SharePoint Services
     2.0 > WSS 3.0 (new server is Windows Server 2008 which only
     supports 3.0) as per [MSDN guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc507614%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
14. Install SQL 2008 SP2
15. Perform TFS migration as per [MSDN
     guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

I tried this all out first on some disposable virtual servers which was very worthwhile.  The whole process (including testing, communicating to users, etc.) has taken well over a week!

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I would do it the opposite way:  [move your TFS 2005 instance] to the new hardware, then do the upgrade from 2005 to 2008.  The reason being:  in the unlikely event that something goes wrong in the upgrade, you've still got a working 2005 server instance on your old hardware.

(If you do the upgrade on your existing 2005 server and something were to go wrong, that restore from backup could take a while.)

Comment: this looks like a more sensible option.  I am due to start working on this today so will post back when I'm done (hopefully later this week).

Comment: I ultimately couldn't follow your advice.  We had to also migrate from Windows Server 2003 to 2008 and TFS 2005 is not supported on 2008.  I will post what I did in a separate answer for future reference.  Thanks for your help.